# Can a business idea be patented (in India)?

Tags: patentability, intellectual-property, india

I have a business idea which will take a year atleast to implement it. Just want to ask if a business idea is patentable or not (In India)?

Answer (score 3):

No, as per [Indian patent act,](http://www.ipindia.nic.in/writereaddata/Portal/IPOAct/1_31_1_patent-act-1970-11march2015.pdf) 1970. **section 3(k)** a mathematical or **business methods** or a computer program *per se* or algorithms are not patentable.

Comment: An actual link to the regulation would make this excellent answer even better.

Comment: @Eric Shain there is no web page but the link gives whole patent act  http://www.ipindia.nic.in/writereaddata/Portal/IPOAct/1_31_1_patent-act-1970-11march2015.pdf

Comment: Just add that link to the answer. Thanks.